# Is there a way to split every string in an array and retrieve the 5th bit each time, adding to a total?

Tags: c#, arrays, split

Hi sorry guys I'm pretty new to C# and programming in general.

I have a text file that I'm reading from which contains 10 lines (all but the first of which are relevant).

I want to split each line (besides the first since it's only one word) by the commas, then retrieve the 5th one along of each line, adding it to a total.

Currently all I have been able to do is essentially split and add the same value to the total 10 times, instead of adding the 9 different values together, or face a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException".

```
            int totalValues = 0;

            string[] larray = lines.ToArray(); //create array from list
            string vehicleValue;

            for (int i = 0; i < larray.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] bits = larray[i].Split(','); 
                vehicleValue = bits[4];
                int vvint = int.Parse(vehicleValue);
                totalValues = totalValues + vvint; 
            }
            totalValue.Text = totalValues.ToString();
```

As it stands, the above code results in a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" highlighting "vehicleValue = bits [4];"

Every line of the file looks like this, besides the first one.

```
Car,Ford,GT40,1964,250000,987,Red,A1,2,4,FALSE
```

The value I want out of this specific line would be '250000' - the 5th one along. I'm trying to get the 5th one along from every line.

Comment: `bits[4]` is the fifth item in the array as indexing starts from zero, to get the fourth item you should get `bits[3]`

Comment: If the first one needs to be skipped you probably want to start the loop from 1? At which line does the error happen, meaning what is the value of `i` and what is `lines[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to parse also the first line (which does not contain enough entries so you get the exception). You can skip the first line by starting your iteration at index 1:

```
        int totalValues = 0;

        string[] larray = lines.ToArray(); //create array from list
        string vehicleValue;

        for (int i = 1; i < larray.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] bits = larray[i].Split(','); 
            vehicleValue = bits[4];
            int vvint = int.Parse(vehicleValue);
            totalValues = totalValues + vvint; 
        }
        totalValue.Text = totalValues.ToString();
```

Comment: By the way, with Linq, it may be written `var totalValues = lines.Skip(1).Sum(line => { var bits = line.Split(','); var vehicleValue = bits[4]; var vvint = int.Parse(vehicleValue); return vvint; }); totalValue.Text = totalValues.ToString();`. Depending on preference, it can be condensed even further, so the entire code would be something like `totalValue.Text = lines.Skip(1).Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[4])).ToString();`.

Answer (score 0):

`bits[4]` is the fifth item in the array as indexing starts from zero, to get the fourth item you should get `bits[3]`

```
int totalValues = 0;

string[] larray = lines.ToArray(); //create array from list
string vehicleValue;

for (int i = 0; i < larray.Length; i++)
{
    string[] bits = larray[i].Split(','); 
    vehicleValue = bits[3];
    int vvint = int.Parse(bits[3]);
    totalValues = totalValues + vvint; 
}
totalValue.Text = totalValues.ToString();
```

Comment: He said he indeed wanted the 5th item.

Comment: Was a typo in the question, fixed now. Sorry!